# React- page won't refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My current situation:

I want to click on an image and then navigate to a /details page. If I click on the image, the url gets refreshed but my component is not loaded.

I tried some solutions I found like window.location.reload(). This approach works, but I have to click 2 times on the image to refresh the page and I don't understand why? So it doesn't solve my problem.

I found out that if I insert the Link, whether it is an image or a button, into the navbar the link works fine and the page gets refreshed. Only if I insert the Link into a page, it dont works.

Maybe it's because the Navbar component is outside the Switch component? (see below) That's the only difference. Maybe someone of you has an idea.

```
<React.Fragment>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Router exact path="/">
            <ProductList />
          </Router>

          <Router path="/details">
            <Details />
          </Router>

          <Router path="/cart">
            <Cart />
          </Router>

          <Router>
            <Default />
          </Router>
        </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: we need a bit more context, but using a windows.location.reload() is big no no in this case. Make sure that your router is redirecting properly so event you attached on image do a real push to `/detail` page, make sure that details component page do render what it should to render.

Comment: @vaske The details component renders the page properly. I even tried just to render a simple button which navigates to /details because I thought my code was wrong but anyway it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you mean to push to /detail? My code which navigates to the /details page looks like this 
<Link to="/produkt"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    value.handleDetail(id)
                                }}>
                                    <img src={img} alt="product" className="card-img-top" />
                                </Link>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only one `Router` component (which should be outside the `Switch`), and for the separate routes you should use `Route`.